# Best fit for entities of fixed size but with normalized positions

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, geometry

Imagine I have an array of entities composed of a *normalized position* (t) and a *width*.

```
struct Entity 
{ 
    float t;       // left position as a percentage of the parent's size
    float width;   // width of the entity in absolute values
}
```

Once I decide on a *size* for the parent, I can easily render all entities like this:

```
void Draw(Entity[] entities, float size) 
{
    foreach(var entity in entities) 
    {
        var x = entity.t * size;
        Draw(x, entity.width);       // x corresponds to left side, not center
    }
}
```

**I'm having a hard time figuring out how to calculate the minimum `size` that, for any given set of entities, allows them to be rendered without their bounds intersecting.**

---

If you're curious about the use case for this, it's a helper function that I need to solve some edges cases on a sheet music rendering system. Chord labels are placed at the end of the layout cycle on top of the sheet music, and their positions need to be properly aligned with the corresponding musical content. But there are cases where satisfying this constraint means that there isn't enough space on the measure to fit the labels. I need this function to figure out if there's not enough space in advance, and if not, ask the measure to grow by the missing amount.

Comment: What size fonts are you using.  You should start with the size of the text since you want to be able to read the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to move the labels i.e. `t` should always be position of exactly left end of the label, I think this simple code does what you need

```
    static float CalcMinWidth(IList<Entity> entities)
    {
        var count = entities.Count;
        List<Entity> local = new List<Entity>(count + 1);
        local.AddRange(entities);
        local.Add(new Entity(1, 0)); // add one that marks "end"
        local.Sort((e1, e2) => Comparer<float>.Default.Compare(e1.t, e2.t));

        float minReqW = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var e1 = local[i];
            var e2 = local[i + 1];
            var reqW = e1.width / (e2.t - e1.t);
            if (reqW > minReqW)
                minReqW = reqW;
        }
        return minReqW;
    }
```

The idea is that minimal width is specified by some particular entity `e1` that should not overlap with the next entity `e2` (or the end which is marked in the code by a fake entity `(1.0, 0.0)`). So what we have is following equation:

```
  e1.t * required_width + e1.width < e2.t * required_width
```

Or if you solve it for `required_width` you'll get

```
  e1.width / (e2.t - e1.t) < required_width
```

Comment: I haven't applied it to my problem yet, but I ran a quick JS fiddle to test it, and it appears to be working perfectly (http://i.imgur.com/HPKhY4J.png). Thank you very much!